# DOM access of meteor templates using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

This is my **meteor** template:

```
{{#each p}}
<div class="cpl">
<div class="chat-post">
    <li class="post">
        <div class="nm" id={{_id}}>
            <a>{{username}}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="con">{{content}}</div>
        <div class="cnm">
            <div class="t">{{time}}</div>
            <div class="m" id="cm">
                <a>message </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
 </div></div>
 {{/each}}
```

//TEMPLATE FOR PF

```
    <template name="pf">
  <form id="post-box">
  <textarea id="new" required></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Post</button>
  </form>
  </template>
```

//THIS IS MY HELPERS AND EVENT HANDLERS FOR PF AND PC,COLLECTION NAME ROST

```
   Template.pc.helpers({
  p: function(){
    return Rost.find({}, {sort:{created:-1}});
  }
});



Template.pf.events({
  'submit form': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var content= document.getElementById('new').value;


 var date= new Date(),
 h=(date.getHours()<10?'0':'') +date.getHours(),
 m=(date.getMinutes()<10?'0':'')+date.getMinutes();
var time=h+':'+m;
 var username= Meteor.user().username;
    Rost.insert({
      content: content,
      created:date,
      time:time,
      username: username
    });
    event.target.reset();
  }
});
```

I am using meteor and mongo as DB where `{{username}}`, `{{content}}` and `{{time}}` are variables of object. 
How can I access `{{username}}` using JavaScript?

Comment: You have many way to do that. Do you want to only the value of username? The DOM node? In Meteor way? Jquery way? Vanilla js?

Comment: i want the value n dom node

Answer (score 0):

Inside your helper function, you should already have access to this data via the this context variable, or Template.instance().data.  Your event handler should look like:

```
'click cssSelector'(event,instance) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

As you can see, the second parameter is the template instance, so you have access to the data with instance.data, or you use event.currentTarget to determine the element that was click on and go from there.  Please post your helpers or event handling code so that we can see what you are trying do and having problem with.

Comment: Template.pc.helpers({
  p: function(){
    return Rost.find({}, {sort:{created:-1}});
  }
});
Template.pf.events({
  'submit form': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var content= document.getElementById('new').value;


 var date= new Date(),
 h=(date.getHours()<10?'0':'') +date.getHours(),
 m=(date.getMinutes()<10?'0':'')+date.getMinutes();
var time=h+':'+m;
 var username= Meteor.user().username;
    Rost.insert({
      content: content,
      created:date,
      time:time,
      username: username
    });
    event.target.reset();
  }
});

Comment: I cannot see what you are try to do.  When you click on the username from the pc template, I do not know what you want to do with the pf template.  Anyway to read the username from the pc template: `Template.pc.events({'click .nm a'(event,template) {event.preventDefault(); alert($.trim($(event.currentTarget).text()));}})`.  Please check.

Comment: its an group chat application ....i needed the value of the {{username}} from pc template so that  i can remove 'message' link for current user[one doesn't message it self]and to make the posts of current user to float on the other side .........for that i need to get value of {{username}} n then i have to compare that if username == curent user ..then change the visibility of link 'message' to hidden and make that post float on other side